# unable to initialize class property inside ngOnit error

Tags: angular, typescript, ngoninit

I'm getting an error that says monetization has no inializer. I'm also getting an error inside ngOninit that says monetization is not assignable to type string | null.

```
export class MoviesPageComponent implements OnInit {
  movies: MovieResults[] = [];
  monetization: string;
  constructor(private getMovies: GetMoviesService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.monetization = params.get('monetization');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because `monetization` is not initialized in the constructor.

What you'll need to do, is make the property optional.

```
export class MoviesPageComponent implements OnInit {
  movies: MovieResults[] = [];
  monetization?: string; // <-- add ? here
  constructor(private getMovies: GetMoviesService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.monetization = params.get('monetization');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the function specification of [ParamMap.get](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap#get)...

```ts
get(name: string): string | null
```

the return type is `string | null`, however type of `monetization` property is

```ts
monetization: string;
```

and the assignment fails due to type inconsistency when we are doing

```ts
 this.monetization = params.get('monetization'); //<-- Return type is string | null
```

To fix this,

1. Make the property optional, as stated in the other answer. Like `monetization?: string`. Suffixing the property name with a `?` implicits an `undefined` in the type
2. Or, provide a default to satisfy null-ness of the value after reading from `ParamMap.get(...)`. Like `this.monetization = params.get('monetization') ?? '';`
3. If uncomfortable with making property optional, you can explicitly provide `string | undefined | null` to the type of the property. Like `monetization: string | null | undefined`.